# How do I get Axios to hit routes in monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am using a monorepo-styled build and I am struggling to get routes to hit properly. I am clicking my button:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("button clicked");
    axios.get('/', {
      params: {
        username: "John1904",
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  };
```

And I am getting the `index.ts` file, which makes sense. When I attempt to use `'/users` or `/users/`, it doesn't work. I get

```
>GET http://localhost:3000/users?username=John1904 404 (Not Found)
>Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404'
```

This is in the browser console, while nothing else shows in my terminal.

My index.ts that is handling routes is:

```
const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use('/', (_req, res) => res.status(200).send('Service online'));

app.use(errorHandler);
app.use(notFoundHandler);
```

And my `server/src/routes/users/router.ts` file is:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const items = await UserService.findAll();

    res.status(200).send(items);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(unwrapRouterErrorMessage(e));
  }
});
```

So why is my request not going into the `app.use('/users', usersRouter);`?

Comment: What port is your frontend app running on, and what port is your backend running on? NextJS is server-side-rendering, `react-router` is client-side rendering. How certain are you of your code and what should actually be working and where?

Comment: My frontend is running on 3000 and backend is running on 3006. I am 70% sure of the code. I am not sure by any means of what should and shouldn't be working, but I know the basic layout seems to be properly setup.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for asking about the ports, because I checked the URL requests in the dev tools and it was all going through to the frontend and not hitting the backend. Everything was going to the port 3000 instead of 3006. For now I hardcoded the route to go to `http://localhost:3006/` and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: You should read up on setting a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for the API requests.